# How make 2 dictionaries in python, separate with a space in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need help I would like to know how I can make 2 dictionaries in python, separate with a space in a .txt file.

the look of the file like this :

```
value1 value10
value2 value20
value3 value30

var1 var10
var2 var20
var3 var30
```

and I would like that the output like this :

```
{'value1': value10, 'value2': value20, 'value3': value30}, {'var1': var10, 'var2': var20, 'var3': var30}
```

And I have tested a lot of possibilities but this code doesn't work because actually, I have this

```
{'value1': 'value10'}
{'value1': 'value10', 'value2': 'value20'}
{'value1': 'value10', 'value2': 'value20', 'value3': 'value30'}
{'value1': 'value10', 'value2': 'value20', 'value3': 'value30', 'var1': 'var10'}
{'value1': 'value10', 'value2': 'value20', 'value3': 'value30', 'var1': 'var10', 'var2': 'var20'}
{'value1': 'value10', 'value2': 'value20', 'value3': 'value30', 'var1': 'var10', 'var2': 'var20', 'var3': '
```

Can you help me please,
my code actually is that:

```
dictionnary = {}

lector = open("file.txt","r")
file = lector.readlines()

for i in range(0,len(file)):

  if len(file[i].split()) == 2 :
    first_val = file[i].split()[0]
    second_val = file[i].split()[1]

    dictionnary.update({first_val : second_val})
    print(dictionnary)
```

Comment: why not just use something like JSON for your file?

Comment: because I need to make this in python

Comment: You need to specify what "doesn't work" looks like.  Expected and actual.  Your code works fine to create one dictionary, you need to make a new one when you see a blank line

Comment: @Eitoon so what? What does it being in Python have to do with using JSON?

Comment: @Cireo I have edited my post now you can see the problem I have

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I need to make my dictionary without JSON for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to detect the empty line (equivalently, double newline). Here is how to do it with a list comprehension:

```
with open("file.txt", "rt") as r:
    contents = r.read()

dicts = [
    dict(
        line.split(" ", 1)
        for line in block.split("\n")
    )
    for block in contents.strip().split("\n\n")
]
dicts
# => [{'value1': 'value10', 'value2': 'value20', 'value3': 'value30'}, {'var1': 'var10', 'var2': 'var20', 'var3': 'var30'}]
```

I take in the entire file, intending to split lines manually. First I remove the outermost newlines, if any, then split on inner double newlines. This produces blocks; splitting those by newline gives lines, which can be split by space to produce key and value. All key-value pairs of a block are fed into the `dict` constructor.

Doing it more closely to what you did:

```
current = {}
dicts = []
for line in file:
    items = line.split(" ", 1)
    if len(items) == 2:
        current[items[0]] = items[1]
    else:
        dicts.append(current)
        current = {}
if current:
    dicts.append(current)
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's work and I have seen my problem, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group your blocks:

```
from itertools import groupby

out = [
    dict(map(str.split, g))
    for v, g in groupby(
        open("your_file.txt", "r"), lambda line: len(line.split()) == 2
    )
    if v
]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'value1': 'value10', 'value2': 'value20', 'value3': 'value30'}, {'var1': 'var10', 'var2': 'var20', 'var3': 'var30'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a generator to group together each series of data into a `dict`, then make the generator into a list.

```py
def get_dicts(lines):
    d = {}
    for line in lines:
        if line == "\n" and d:
            yield d
            d = {}
        else:
            k, v = line.split(' ')
            d[k] = v.strip()
    if d:
        yield d


def main():
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        output = list(get_dicts(f.readlines()))
        print(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```py
[{'value1': 'value10', 'value2': 'value20', 'value3': 'value30'}, {'var1': 'var10', 'var2': 'var20', 'var3': 'var30'}]
```